# *.aux file not generated

Tags: biblatex, auxiliary-files

I am using `\documentclass[margin]{res}`. On running latex/xelatex, `*.aux` file is not generated. Because of this the references in the document are not being cited. I am using `biblatex` for citations.

What might be wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

By default (or design), the [`res` documentclass](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) does not create an auxiliary file since it executes

```
\nofiles         % resume's don't need .aux files
```

around line 200. Modify your main file to resemble:

```
\let\nofiles\relax % Void the \nofiles command
\documentclass[margin]{res}% Resume documentclass (http://ctan.org/pkg/res)
...
```

Alternatively, although not preferred, you will have to comment out this line in order for the document to generate `.aux` files.

Comment: Why on Earth does it do that?!

Comment: @werner I was sure your solution would eliminate my problem, but even after generating .aux file, my pdf has no bookmarks (I use the same 'hyperref' seeting as usual). Any idea, what could be the problem?

Comment: @homo_loquens: Yes. The [`res` class](http://ctan.org/pkg/res) modified the traditional `\section` commands as well, so they don't function as expected. If you want to introduce bookmarks at specific locations in your resume, consider using some of the techniques employed by the [`bookmark` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark).

Comment: @werner I don't want them at specific place, I want my usual sections to be my usual bookmarks) Any suggestions on doing this? Simply putting 'bookmark' package doesn't solve the issue...