# Keep getting "aux file" error with the lastpage package

Tags: resume, lastpage

Keep getting "aux file" error with the `lastpage` package. The same code is working in another file but not in this one (code furnished here). Please help! Thank you!

```
\documentclass[margin, 11pt]{res}
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.1in}
\usepackage{helvet}                  % Default font is the helvetica postscript font
\usepackage{lastpage}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}                % http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr
  \pagestyle{fancy}                  % Set default page style to fancy
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove header rule
  \fancyhead{}                       % Remove all header contents
  \cfoot{Parul Gupta\\ Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
                                     % Page X of Y in the footer (centered)

\begin{document}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   NAME AND ADDRESS SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{\large\bf Parul Gupta} % Your name at the top

\moveleft\hoffset\vbox{\hrule width\resumewidth height 0.25pt}\smallskip % Horizontal line after name; adjust line thickness by changing the '1pt'

\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{add line 1 } % Your address
\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{add line 2}
%\moveleft.5\hoffset\centerline{}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{resume}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Have only included the preamble here, so didn't write \end{document}. \documentclass{} is already here.

Comment: Actually, this problem is similar to [`*.aux` file not generated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27139/5764).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As part of the [`res.cls`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/res) document class, it executes:

```
\nofiles         % resume's don't need .aux files
```

This avoid the creation of auxiliary files, needed when using references (which [`lastpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/lastpage) requires). So, add

```
\let\nofiles\relax
```

*before* loading the document class.

Comment: Worked!! Thank you so much! Had been breaking my head over this for the past one hour!

Comment: @Parul: Consider using a more modern resume package, like [`moderncv`](http://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv), for example.